# url conf error ----edit.html not found

Tags: django-views

I have been doing a project but I can't post a request to the edit.html and details.html.

This is my code:

dog_app/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.index),
    url(r'^create$',views.create),
    url(r'^edit/(?P<id>\d+)$', views.edit),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/details/$', views.details),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from models import Dog

def edit(request, id):
     dog=Dog.objects.get(id=id)
     context={'dog': dog}
     return render(request,'dog_app/edit.html',context)


def details(request, id):
     dog=Dog.objects.get(pk=id)
     context={"dog": dog}
     return render(request,'dog_app/details.html',context)
```

The error:
[image: Page not found]